# JSON httpget URIsyntaxexception with illegal character in query

Tags: android, json, http-get, illegal-characters

07-25 20:05:28.276: ERROR/log_tag(940): Error in http connection java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 58: 
http://localhost/test/parsejsonstrtodatabase.php?JSON=[{"endtime":"2011-07-19 08:21:32","clientid":1001005,"lastupdate":"2011-07-19 08:21:32","empid":23456,"starttime":"2011-07-19 08:21:32","lastname":"Senden","tckey":1,"firstname":"Kim","phonenum":2147483647,"clientkey":1001005},{"endtime":"2011-07-19 08:24:43","clientid":1001002,"lastupdate":"2011-07-19 08:24:43","empid":12345,"starttime":"2011-07-19 08:24:43","lastname":"Frenzo","tckey":2,"firstname":"Mary","phonenum":2147483647,"clientkey":1001002}]

Try to use httpget to send the JSON string to remote server from Android, but failed at this step, I am not very sure what may be wrong, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Essentially, some JSON parser are strict.

In your JSON you have key.values like

```
"clientkey" : 1001002
```

While some parsers allow this, others are expecting to be wrapper up like

```
"clientkey" : "1001002"
```

JSON doesn't differential String literal values from number values by the `" "` quotes, essentially everything should be wrapped up.